# GA Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using Google Analytics API to query data from Google for multiple view ID's using a loop on this query (Google2Pandas package) in Python:

```
query = {
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': ids,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2015-01-01', 'endDate': '2017-12-31'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:adClicks'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:adCost'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:CPC'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:bounceRate'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:pageviewsPerSession'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:goal6ConversionRate'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:goal6Completions'},
                  {'expression': 'ga:goal6Value'}],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:campaign'},
                     {'name': 'ga:date'}]
    }]
  }
```

However, after around 15 views have been queried an error pops up:

> https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Insufficient tokens for quota 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:632227033299'."

Which I assume is GA telling me "Stop spamming me with requests". I've added a `time.sleep(5)` and increased it to 20 afterward, but this still comes up.

Anyone has encountered this problem and have found ways to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried using a `quotaUser` parameter in the URL?